# Spotify API get playlist tracks offset parameter not working

Tags: python, api, spotify, offset, playlist

I try to get a playlist from the Spotify API that contains more than 100 tracks. Since there is a rate limit of 100, I try to change the offset parameter each request to get the next 100 tracks. I tried the python library spotipy and tekore, but when I change the offset parameter, I still get the first 100 tracks of the playlist. It doesn't seem to work. I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59441606/spotipy-how-do-i-get-songs-from-a-playlist-starting-at-a-given-index), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086287/spotipy-how-to-read-more-than-100-tracks-from-a-playlist). I also tried to add the query to the url, but I still get the first 100 tracks. What am I missing out?

```
#using tekore
app_token = tk.request_client_token(client_id, client_secret)
tekore = tk.Spotify(app_token)
playlist = tekore.playlist_items(playlist_id=playlist_id, fields=["tracks.items.track.name"], offset=300)

# using spotipy
spotipy = sp.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id, client_secret))
response = spotipy.playlist_tracks(playlist_id, fields=["tracks.items.track.name"], offset=400)

#using url
r = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'playlists/' + playlist_id + "?offset=100", headers=headers)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, having read the same other posts... I'm using the AutoHotkey Spotify.ahk class but the issue is identical. Adding "?offset=100" to the URL has no effect. The API always returns the first 100 tracks. I know parameters added to the URL are correctly sent to the API. For example, adding "?limit=200" returns the expected error as this exceed the max items number set by the API. But why is the "offset=100" parameter is ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JSON returned by the API, I found that the endpoint to get the playlist `BASE_URL + 'playlists/' + playlist_id` returns info about the playlist and includes the 100 first tracks in the `tracks.items` array. This endpoint does not support the `offset` parameter.

To get the remaining tracks, I used the `BASE_URL + 'playlists/' + playlist_id + '/tracks?offset=100'`. This endpoint supports the `limit` and `offset` parameters. It returns the tracks in the `items` array. All you have to do is loop this API call incrementing `offset` by 100 until the JSON return an empty `items` array.

Comment: I did not use Python to do it. I used the AutoHotkey class [Spotify.ahk](https://github.com/CloakerSmoker/Spotify.ahk) that I modified to support tracks paging. I could post the modified AHK code if someone needs it.